# Can ${var} parameter expansion expressions be nested in bash?

Tags: bash

What I have is this:

```
progname=${0%.*}
progname=${progname##*/}
```

Can this be nested (or not) into one line, i.e. a single expression?

I'm trying to strip the path and extension off of a script name so that only the base name is left. The above two lines work fine. My 'C' nature is simply driving me to obfuscate these even more.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If by nest, you mean something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export HELLO="HELLO"
export HELLOWORLD="Hello, world!"

echo ${${HELLO}WORLD}
```

Then no, you can't nest `${var}` expressions. The bash syntax expander won't understand it.

However, if I understand your problem right, you might look at using the `basename` command - it strips the path from a given filename, and if given the extension, will strip that also. For example, running `basename /some/path/to/script.sh .sh` will return `script`.

Comment: If you're using indices though, they can be, correct? e.g., `ARR=('foo' 'bar' 'bogus'); i=0; while /bin/true ; do echo ${ARR[$i]} ; i=(( (i + 1) % 3 )); done` which is obviously useless as code but works as an example.

Comment: Actually, this *is* supported in certain cases, at least in `bash` and `ksh`. This works: `x=yyy; y=xxxyyy; echo ${y%${x}}`. I think the important bit is that the nested expansion is an argument of one of the operators. I've not seen that it's documented really well, though.

Comment: This isn't working for me, I get bash: ${${HELLO}WORLD}: bad substitution.  Any Ideas?  I'm on fedora.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas, as @Tim said, "no, you can't nest expressions". The example `echo ${${HELLO}WORLD}` illustrates *this* impossibility.

Comment: Instead of *indirect expansion*, you could use *nameref* for building variable name! [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61364880/1765658)

Comment: Can the expansion occur on the LHS like it does in Makefiles?

Answer (score 86):

Bash supports indirect expansion:

```
$ FOO_BAR="foobar"
$ foo=FOO
$ foobar=${foo}_BAR
$ echo ${foobar}
FOO_BAR
$ echo ${!foobar}
foobar
```

This should support the nesting you are looking for.

Comment: Hi what does the ! means in shell? It means replace with foobar's value here?

Comment: Great example. What would one do in this case if they didn't have the indirection parameter expansion available?

Comment: This worked great, thanks! :)  Unfortunately I made a minor typo that made me question that fact and google things for an hour, haha.

Comment: @Mike `${var}` is the value stored in the variable named `var` but `${!var}` is the value stored in the variable who's name is stored in `${var}`. It's a form of  indirection.

Answer (score 25):

The following option has worked for me:

```
NAME="par1-par2-par3"
echo $(TMP=${NAME%-*};echo ${TMP##*-})
```

Output is:

```
par2
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: Brilliant. I only wonder, why without the second (inner) `echo` it treats `par2` as a command?

Comment: This creates a sub-shell. Parameter expansion itself does not create a sub-shell.

Comment: Then, to not create a sub-shell: `TMP=${NAME%-*};echo ${TMP##*-}` + `unset TMP` if we want to "reset" `TMP` variable

Comment: @AS try:  `NAME="par1-par2-par3"; read -a var <<<${NAME//-/ }; echo ${var[1]}` ! Read [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15988793/1765658)

Answer (score 20):

An old thread but perhaps the answer is the use of Indirection:${!PARAMETER}

For e.g., consider the following lines:

```
H="abc"
PARAM="H"
echo ${!PARAM} #gives abc
```

Comment: Surely this is the same solution as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14204692/4847772)?

Answer (score 14):

This nesting does not appear to be possible in bash, but it works in zsh:

```
progname=${${0%.*}##*/}
```

Answer (score 10):

Expressions like `${${a}}` do not work. To work around it, you can use `eval`:

```
b=value
a=b
eval aval=\$$a
echo $aval
```

Output is

`value`

Answer (score 8):

Actually it is possible to create nested variables in bash, using two steps.

Here is a test script based upon the post by Tim, using the idea suggested by user1956358.

```
#!/bin/bash
export HELLO="HELLO"
export HELLOWORLD="Hello, world!"

# This command does not work properly in bash
echo ${${HELLO}WORLD}

# However, a two-step process does work
export TEMP=${HELLO}WORLD
echo ${!TEMP}
```

The output is:

```
Hello, world!
```

There are lots of neat tricks explained by running '**info bash**' from the command line, then searching for '**Shell Parameter Expansion**'. I've been reading a few myself today, just lost about 20 minutes of my day, but my scripts are going to get a lot better...

Update: After more reading I suggest this alternative per your initial question.

```
progname=${0##*/}
```

It returns

```
bash
```

Comment: The OP asked if nested expansion is possible in bash, and basically you answer (which is correct): No, you need to have to expand expression one into a temporary variable and then use the second expression on that variable.  Pattern nesting is, however,   supported in other shells.

Answer (score 6):

As there is already a lot of answer there, I just want to present **two** different ways for doing both: *nesting parameter expansion* **and** *variable name manipulation*. (So you will find four different answer there:).

### *Parameter expansion* not really nested, but done in one line:

#### Without semicolon (`;`) nor newline:

```
progname=${0%.*} progname=${progname##*/}
```

#### Another way: you could use a fork to `basename`

```
progname=$(basename ${0%.*})
```

This will make the job.

### About *concatenating* variable name

If you want to *construct varname*, you could

#### use *indirect expansion*

```
foobar="baz"
varname="foo"
varname+="bar"
echo ${!varname}
baz
```

#### or use *nameref*

```
foobar="baz"
bar="foo"
declare -n reffoobar=${bar}bar
echo $reffoobar
baz
```

Comment: Wow. I can see nameref getting me into a lot of trouble. Just because it's there, should I use it? And will I remember such obscurity in a week's time?

Answer (score 5):

There is a 1 line solution to the OP's original question, the basename of a script with the file extension stripped:

```bash
progname=$(tmp=${0%.*} ; echo ${tmp##*/})
```

Here's another, but, using a cheat for basename:

```bash
progname=$(basename ${0%.*})
```

Other answers have wandered away from the OP's original question and focused on whether it's possible to just expand the result of expressions with `${!var}` but came across the limitation that `var` must explicitly match an variable name. Having said that, there's nothing stopping you having a 1-liner answer if you chain the expressions together with a semicolon.

```
ANIMAL=CAT
BABYCAT=KITTEN
tmp=BABY${ANIMAL} ; ANSWER=${!tmp} # ANSWER=KITTEN
```

If you want to make this appear like a single statement, you can nest it in a subshell, i.e.

```
ANSWER=$( tmp=BABY${ANIMAL) ; echo ${!tmp} ) # ANSWER=KITTEN
```

An interesting usage is indirection works on arguments of a bash function. Then, you can nest your bash function calls to achieve multilevel nested indirection because we are allowed to do nested commands:

Here's a demonstration of indirection of an expression:

```bash
deref() { echo ${!1} ; }
ANIMAL=CAT
BABYCAT=KITTEN
deref BABY${ANIMAL} # Outputs: KITTEN
```

Here's a demonstration of multi level indirection thru nested commands:

```bash
deref() { echo ${!1} ; }
export AA=BB
export BB=CC
export CC=Hiya
deref AA # Outputs: BB
deref $(deref AA) # Outputs: CC
deref $(deref $(deref AA)) # Outputs: Hiya
```

Comment: Thanks for the indirection explanation! It is indeed a bit unfortunate that it can only be used to reference existing variable names. Of course a oneliner can be made but involving the assignment of a temporary variable is what I was trying to avoid, at the end of the day.

Comment: @steven-lu what about my `deref()` function? If you have that declared, you can have your oneliner without a temporary variable?

Comment: By any reasonable measure, that’s like twice to three times more confusing for maintenance than use of a temp variable  reminds me of C preprocessor abuse

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an ancient thread, but here are my 2 cents.

Here's an (admittedly kludgy) bash function which allows for the required functionality:

```
read_var() {
  set | grep ^$1\\b | sed s/^$1=//
}
```

Here's a short test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read_var() {
  set | grep ^$1\\b | sed s/^$1=//
}

FOO=12
BAR=34

ABC_VAR=FOO
DEF_VAR=BAR

for a in ABC DEF; do
  echo $a = $(read_var $(read_var ${a}_VAR))
done
```

The output is, as expected:

```
ABC = 12
DEF = 34
```

Comment: I know this is very old now, but you could do away with the grep and use sed -n p as: `set | sed -n s/^$1=//p` . BTW nice hack.

Answer (score 1):

The basename bultin could help with this, since you're specifically splitting on / in one part:

```
user@host# var=/path/to/file.extension
user@host# basename ${var%%.*}
file
user@host#
```

It's not really faster than the two line variant, but it is just one line using built-in functionality.  Or, use zsh/ksh which can do the pattern nesting thing. :)

Comment: sorry about the formatting.  Just try it. :)  var=$( basename ${var%%.*} )

Comment: or use the bash-specific basename extension removal as Tim said and I missed... :D

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a very old thread, this device is ideal for either directly or randomly selecting a file/directory for processing (playing tunes, picking a film to watch or book to read, etc).

In bash I believe it is generally true that you cannot directly nest any two expansions of the same type, but if you can separate them with some different kind of expansion, it can be done.

```
e=($(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d))
c=${2:-${e[$((RANDOM%${#e[@]}))]}}
```

Explanation: e is an array of directory names, c the selected directory, either  named explicitly as $2,

```
${2:-...}
```

where ... is the alternative random selection   given by

```
${e[$((RANDOM%${#e[@]}))]}
```

where the

```
$((RANDOM%...))
```

number generated by bash is divided by the number of items in array e, given by

```
${#e[@]}
```

yielding the remainder (from the % operator) that becomes the index to array e

```
${e[...]}
```

Thus you have four nested expansions.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you follow the bellow shown way of taking on intermediate step :

```
export HELLO="HELLO"
export HELLOWORLD="Hello, world!"

varname=${HELLO}WORLD
echo ${!varname}
```

Comment: but is not shared by other shells.. not that I wanted that but something close.

Comment: Surely this is the same solution as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14204692/4847772)?

Answer (score 0):

If the motivation is to "obfuscate" (I would say streamline) array processing in the spirit of Python's "comprehensions", create a helper function that performs the operations in sequence.

```
function fixupnames()
   {
   pre=$1 ; suf=$2 ; shift ; shift ; args=($@)
   args=(${args[@]/#/${pre}-})
   args=(${args[@]/%/-${suf}})
   echo ${args[@]}
   }
```

You can use the result with a nice one-liner.

```
$ echo $(fixupnames a b abc def ghi)
a-abc-b a-def-b a-ghi-b
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal of "to strip the path and extension off of a script name so that only the base name is left" is actually possible in a single Bash expression without subshells or commands. Before facing the XY problem of nested parameter expansion, it's important to ask whether [`${parameter%word}`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion:%7E:text=the%20resultant%20list.-,%24%7Bparameter%25word%7D,-%24%7Bparameter%25%25) and [`${parameter##word}`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion:%7E:text=%23word%7D-,%24%7Bparameter%23%23word%7D,-Remove%20matching%20prefix) are the right tools for the job. Since this is a filepath, it is possible to use [`${parameter//pattern/string}`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion:%7E:text=%24%7Bparameter//pattern/string%7D) with the [`@(pattern‐list)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion:%7E:text=the%20given%20patterns-,%40(pattern%2Dlist),-Matches%20one%20of) glob provided by `shopt -s extglob` (enabled by default). You can do what you want with the following:

```bash
progname="${0//@(*\/|.*)}"
```

#### Example

```bash
$ BASH_ARGV0=/usr/share/man/man7/bash-builtins.7.gz
$ progname="${0//@(*\/|.*)}"
$ echo "$progname"
bash-builtins
```

Note that this does %% instead of %, which is probably what you want, because your uses case seems like it wants `libQt5Gui` for `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.15` not `libQt5Gui.so.5`. Basically this means that it will remove everything after the first dot, not the last dot. I don't know of a way to make the one-liner with ${//} do % instead of %%. If you want the `.so`, you could just add it after the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

eval will allow you to do what you are wanting:

```
export HELLO="HELLO"
export HELLOWORLD="Hello, world!"

eval echo "\${${HELLO}WORLD}"
```

Output: `Hello, world`