# How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, split, scripting

I have this string stored in a variable:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
```

Now I would like to split the strings by `;` delimiter so that I have:

```
ADDR1="bla@some.com"
ADDR2="john@home.com"
```

I don't necessarily need the `ADDR1` and `ADDR2` variables. If they are elements of an array that's even better.

---

After suggestions from the answers below, I ended up with the following which is what I was after:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"

mails=$(echo $IN | tr ";" "\n")

for addr in $mails
do
    echo "> [$addr]"
done
```

Output:

```
> [bla@some.com]
> [john@home.com]
```

There was a solution involving setting [Internal_field_separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) (IFS) to `;`. I am not sure what happened with that answer, how do you reset `IFS` back to default?

RE: `IFS` solution, I tried this and it works, I keep the old `IFS` and then restore it:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"

OIFS=$IFS
IFS=';'
mails2=$IN
for x in $mails2
do
    echo "> [$x]"
done

IFS=$OIFS
```

BTW, when I tried

```
mails2=($IN)
```

I only got the first string when printing it in loop, without brackets around `$IN` it works.

Comment: With regards to your "Edit2": You can simply "unset IFS" and it will return to the default state. There's no need to save and restore it explicitly unless you have some reason to expect that it's already been set to a non-default value.  Moreover, if you're doing this inside a function (and, if you aren't, why not?), you can set IFS as a local variable and it will return to its previous value once you exit the function.

Comment: @BrooksMoses: (a) +1 for using `local IFS=...` where possible; (b) -1 for `unset IFS`, this doesn't exactly reset IFS to its default value, though I believe an unset IFS behaves the same as the default value of IFS ($' \t\n'), however it seems bad practice to be assuming blindly that your code will never be invoked with IFS set to a custom value; (c) another idea is to invoke a subshell: `(IFS=$custom; ...)` when the subshell exits IFS will return to whatever it was originally.

Comment: I just want to have a quick look at the paths to decide where to throw an executable, so I resorted to run `ruby -e "puts ENV.fetch('PATH').split(':')"`. If you want to stay pure bash won't help but using *any scripting language* that has a built-in split is easier.

Comment: This is kind of a drive-by comment, but since the OP used email addresses as the example, has anyone bothered to answer it in a way that is fully RFC 5322 compliant, namely that any quoted string can appear before the @ which means you're going to need regular expressions or some other kind of parser instead of naive use of IFS or other simplistic splitter functions.

Comment: `for x in $(IFS=';';echo $IN); do echo "> [$x]"; done`

Comment: In order to save it as an array I had to place another set of parenthesis and change the `\n` for just a space. So the final line is `mails=($(echo $IN | tr ";" " "))`. So now I can check the elements of `mails` by using the array notation `mails[index]` or just iterating in a loop

Comment: For what it's worth, the `tr` solution doesn't work the same in zsh.

Comment: for `$IFS` see [What is the exact meaning of `IFS=$'\n'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128235/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-ifs-n/66942306#66942306)

Comment: You don't need to save/restore IFS, nor do you need to use 'local'.

```
declare -a OUT;

IFS=';' OUT=( $( echo "$IN") )
```

Is all you need (as implied by @user2037659).

The key is that you can set environment variables local to a single command by putting the assignment(s) before the command.

( Replace the first ';' with a newline for better readability).

IFS= is a particularly useful case.

Comment: You don't need the `$mails2` variable, just do `for x in $IN`. I've put that into a new answer.

Answer (score 1675, accepted):

You can set the [internal field separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) (IFS) variable, and then let it parse into an array. When this happens in a command, then the assignment to `IFS` only takes place to that single command's environment (to `read` ). It then parses the input according to the `IFS` variable value into an array, which we can then iterate over.

This example will parse one line of items separated by `;`, pushing it into an array:

```
IFS=';' read -ra ADDR <<< "$IN"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
  # process "$i"
done
```

This other example is for processing the whole content of `$IN`, each time one line of input separated by `;`:

```
while IFS=';' read -ra ADDR; do
  for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    # process "$i"
  done
done <<< "$IN"
```

Comment: This is probably the best way. How long will IFS persist in it's current value, can it mess up my code by being set when it shouldn't be, and how can I reset it when I'm done with it?

Comment: now after the fix applied, only within the duration of the read command :)

Comment: I knew there was a way with arrays, just couldn't remember what it was. I like setting the IFS but am not sure with the redirect from $IN and go through read just to populate array. Isn't just restoring IFS easier? Anyway +1 fro IFS suggestion, thanks.

Comment: I didn't like this saved="$IFS"; IFS=';'; ADDR=($IN); IFS="$saved" mess. :)

Comment: You can read everything at once without using a while loop:
read -r -d '' -a addr <<< "$in" # The -d '' is key here, it tells read not to stop at the first newline (which is the default -d) but to continue until EOF or a NULL byte (which only occur in binary data).

Comment: lhunath, ah nice idea :) However when i say "-d ''", then it always adds a linefeed as last element to the array. I don't know why that is :(

Comment: Seems to me the natural solution to the problem of splitting a line in bash with a custom word delimiter in a safe manner. Help me a lot.

Comment: +1 Only a side note: shouldn't it be recommendable to keep the old IFS and then restore it? (as shown by stefanB in his edit3) people landing here (sometimes just copying and pasting a solution) might not think about this.

Comment: @LucaBorrione Setting `IFS` on the same line as the `read` with no semicolon or other separator, as opposed to in a separate command, scopes it to that command -- so it's always "restored"; you don't need to do anything manually.

Comment: I noticed that parentheses are needed around $IN. Otherwise the whole string gets put into ADDR[0]. Why is this the case?

Comment: @imagineerThis There is a bug involving herestrings and local changes to IFS that requires `$IN` to be quoted. The bug is fixed in `bash` 4.3.

Comment: Does not parse `newline` (`\n`) correctly, neither when `IN` declared like `IN=$'...'` nor when `IN="..."`. To see it, try `echo $i` in `for` loop, or `declare -p ADDR`. See [that solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24426608/1566267) for a workaround.

Comment: Doesn't process included newlines. Also add a trailing newline.

Comment: This produces an extra empty array elements if the string to split by has more than one character.

Comment: In docker alpine (with `apk add bash`), this approach results in this error `cannot create temp file for here-document: Text file busy`

Comment: What about if I only need the first part?

Comment: Does not work for `IFS='\0'`.

Comment: @lhunath note however that the `-d` flag is an extension and [is not found in the POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html)

Comment: @0andriy Most standard/traditional nix utilities do not (correctly) handle null literals in strings. `tr` is one of the few exceptions. Pipe your null-containing string (the string you are attempting to split) _directly_ from a file or command into `tr` and convert the nulls to some other unique ASCII character first. That new character will now be your delimiter.

Comment: Why can't we just do 
```bash
IFS=';'

for file in "$IN"
do process $file
done
```
instead?

Comment: many thanks for the answer: I tried it on my system (zsh MacOS 11.6.1), but get the following error message : `bad option: -a`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1599):

Taken from *[Bash shell script split array](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-shell-script-split-array-383848/#post3270796)*:

```sh
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
arrIN=(${IN//;/ })
echo ${arrIN[1]}                  # Output: john@home.com
```

Explanation:

This construction replaces all occurrences of `';'` (the initial `//` means global replace) in the string `IN` with `' '` (a single space), then interprets the space-delimited string as an array (that's what the surrounding parentheses do).

The syntax used inside of the curly braces to replace each `';'` character with a `' '` character is called [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

There are some common gotchas:

1. If the original string has spaces, you will need to use [IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting):

- `IFS=':'; arrIN=($IN); unset IFS;`

2. If the original string has spaces *and* the delimiter is a new line, you can set [IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting) with:

- `IFS=$'\n'; arrIN=($IN); unset IFS;`

Comment: I just want to add: this is the simplest of all, you can access array elements with ${arrIN[1]} (starting from zeros of course)

Comment: Found it: the technique of modifying a variable within a ${} is known as 'parameter expansion'.

Comment: If you want to split on a special character such as tilde (~) make sure to escape it: arrIN=(${IN//\~/ })

Comment: No, I don't think this works when there are also spaces present... it's converting the ',' to ' ' and then building a space-separated array.

Comment: Very concise, but there are *caveats for general use*: the shell applies *word splitting* and *expansions* to the string, which may be undesired; just try it with. `IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com;*;broken apart"`. In short: this approach will break, if your tokens contain embedded spaces and/or chars. such as `*` that happen to make a token match filenames in the current folder.

Comment: This is a bad approach for other reasons: For instance, if your string contains `;*;`, then the `*` will be expanded to a list of filenames in the current directory. -1

Comment: You can actually fix the spaces problem by using `IFS` instead of parameter expansion/substitution: `IFS=':' arrIN=($IN)` This is also somewhat more readable in my opinion.

Comment: @KyleStrand That sets `IFS`, then sets `arrIN`, same as if they were executed on separate lines or separated by a `;`. That is, assignments are temporary only if they appear before a *non*-assignment command. So after `IFS=':' arrIN=($IN)`, `echo "$IFS"` gives `:` and words are split on `:` for subsequent commands, which usually isn't wanted. (This is easy to overlook, since `echo $var` is sufficient to check if `$var` is `:`, when `:` is not in `$IFS`.) Therefore, except perhaps at the very end of a script, `IFS=':' arrIN=($IN) IFS=$' \t\n'` or `IFS=':' arrIN=($IN); unset IFS` is preferable.

Comment: @EliahKagan Ah. Is there some benefit to that particular inconsistency?

Comment: @KyleStrand Yes, in that while it makes sense for a variable assignment to be scoped to a command, it doesn't really make sense for one variable assignment to be scoped to another. The shell performs variable/parameter expansion before it assigns values (or runs commands). For example, `x=foo echo $x` doesn't output `foo`, as `$x` is expanded before `foo` is assigned to `x` or `echo` is run. Likewise, if `x=foo y=$x` *were* to assign `foo` to `x` only while `y=$x` ran, then `y` would be assigned the original `$x` (not `foo`) because `$x` would expand before any variable assignments happened.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This could be avoided with `set -f`: `set -f; IN="bla@some.com;*;john@home.com"; arrIN=(${IN//;/ }); echo ${arrIN[1]}`

Comment: @John_West, yes, this approach _can_ be made usable by modifying global state to disable globbing (and taking close control of further global state in the form of `IFS`), but... well, why would you do that when `read -a` is available with none of the risks?

Comment: @Ethan thanks for pointing out the problem with when spaces are present and I am surprised this gotcha was not in the answer. I took the liberty of editing the answer to mention this gotcha and provide a solution for it (and one other gotcha). (@EliahKagan thanks for giving a good solution that is consistent with the original answer.)

Comment: Not sure why `IFS=';' declare -a arr=($IN)` isn't getting more cred here. No need to set any intermediary variables, the IFS change only applies to the one `declare` command, and we expand on the IFS rather than having to change it to something else.

Comment: Shouldn't `IFS=':';` be `IFS=';';` to match the input string? in the later example

Comment: Why does the syntax `arrIN=(${IN//;/ })` break when put inside a for loop, in a bash script?

Comment: Also if you are using strings that have IFS in the process this solution is the only one that won't break the process.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy because its read -A in zsh and i really don't like using build-in functions

Comment: You can write a wrapper around a built-in function that calls the right underlying implementation/usage, if you really want to write a script that works on two mutually-incompatible shells (I strongly prefer to just use an appropriate shebang, and then a guard at the first line that exits if invoked with an incompatible interpreter). By contrast, you *can't* write portability shims for syntax.

Comment: for some reason, `arrIN=(${IN//;/ })` doesn't work for me on a Mac and on Linux... it had to be `arrIN=${IN//;/ }` and I can loop over the two email addresses. Otherwise, the first form, if I `echo $arrIN`, it is only 1 address

Comment: Every time I need to look for something super easy to do in every language and I look at 'simple' answer like this... I wonder what is wrong with bash and its whole community.

Comment: Ohhh man... If I could I would have gave this answer one hundred upvotes

Comment: @nonopolarity For macOS - ZSH needs a different syntax - ref https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444961

So it would be `arrIN=(${(s:;:)IN})` which will create the desired effect.

Comment: many thanks for the answer: I tried it on my system (zsh MacOS 11.6.1), but get the following output : `bla@some.com john@home.com`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 545):

I've seen a couple of answers referencing the `cut` command, but they've all been deleted.  It's a little odd that nobody has elaborated on that, because I think it's one of the more useful commands for doing this type of thing, especially for parsing delimited log files.

In the case of splitting this specific example into a bash script array, `tr` is probably more efficient, but `cut` can be used, and is more effective if you want to pull specific fields from the middle.

**Example:**

```
$ echo "bla@some.com;john@home.com" | cut -d ";" -f 1
bla@some.com
$ echo "bla@some.com;john@home.com" | cut -d ";" -f 2
john@home.com
```

You can obviously put that into a loop, and iterate the -f parameter to pull each field independently.

This gets more useful when you have a delimited log file with rows like this:

```
2015-04-27|12345|some action|an attribute|meta data
```

`cut` is very handy to be able to `cat` this file and select a particular field for further processing.

Comment: Kudos for using `cut`, it's the right tool for the job! Much cleared than any of those shell hacks.

Comment: This approach will only work if you know the number of elements in advance; you'd need to program some more logic around it. It also runs an external tool for every element.

Comment: Excatly waht i was looking for trying to avoid empty string in a csv. Now i can point the exact 'column' value as well. Work with IFS already used in a loop. Better than expected for my situation.

Comment: This answer is worth scrolling down over half a page :)

Comment: @uli42  Have a look at my ***Why not `cut`*** paragraph in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15988793/1765658)!! Here is a little *while* loop, for processing any number of fields in whole line... (But it's not really **quick""!!)

Comment: It's also limited to a single character delimiter. I was searching for a multi-char delimiter cut equivalent, that's how I ended up here...

Answer (score 385):

If you don't mind processing them immediately, I like to do this:

```
for i in $(echo $IN | tr ";" "\n")
do
  # process
done
```

You could use this kind of loop to initialize an array, but there's probably an easier way to do it.

Comment: You should have kept the IFS answer. It taught me something I didn't know, and it definitely made an array, whereas this just makes a cheap substitute.

Comment: I see. Yeah i find doing these silly experiments, i'm going to learn new things each time i'm trying to answer things. I've edited stuff based on #bash IRC feedback and undeleted :)

Comment: You could change it to echo "$IN" | tr ';' '\n' | while read -r ADDY; do # process "$ADDY"; done to make him lucky, i think :) Note that this will fork, and you can't change outer variables from within the loop (that's why i used the <<< "$IN" syntax) then

Comment: To summarize the debate in the comments: *Caveats for general use*: the shell applies *word splitting* and *expansions* to the string, which may be undesired; just try it with. `IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com;*;broken apart"`. In short: this approach will break, if your tokens contain embedded spaces and/or chars. such as `*` that happen to make a token match filenames in the current folder.

Comment: This is very helpful answer. e.g. `IN=abc;def;123`. How can we also print the index number?  `echo $count $i ?`

Comment: I tried to split on `"-c"`, but then `tr` considered it a parameter to itself. I then tried to split on `"\-c"`, but then `tr` split on any `c` in my text.

Comment: please add explanation of what `tr ';' '\n'` means, what is that semi colon lol wtf bro

Answer (score 360):

## Compatible answer

There are a lot of different ways to do this in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

However, it's important to first note that `bash` has many *special* features (so-called *[bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)*) that won't work in any other [shell](/questions/tagged/shell).

In particular, *arrays*, *associative arrays*, and *pattern substitution*, which are used in the solutions in this post as well as others in the thread, are *bashisms* and may not work under other *shells* that many people use.

For instance: on my *Debian GNU/Linux*, there is a *standard* shell called [dash](/questions/tagged/dash); I know many people who like to use another shell called [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh); and there is also a special tool called [busybox](/questions/tagged/busybox) with his own shell interpreter ([ash](/questions/tagged/ash)).

For [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) compatible answer, go to last part of this answer!

### Requested string

The string to be split in the above question is:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
```

I will use a modified version of this string to ensure that my solution is robust to strings containing whitespace, which could break other solutions:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com;Full Name <fulnam@other.org>"
```

### Split string based on delimiter in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (version >=4.2)

In *pure* `bash`, we can create an *array* with elements split by a temporary value for *[IFS](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS)* (the *input field separator*). The IFS, among other things, tells `bash` which character(s) it should treat as a delimiter between elements when defining an array:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com;Full Name <fulnam@other.org>"

# save original IFS value so we can restore it later
oIFS="$IFS"
IFS=";"
declare -a fields=($IN)
IFS="$oIFS"
unset oIFS
```

In newer versions of `bash`, prefixing a command with an IFS definition changes the IFS for that command *only* and resets it to the previous value immediately afterwards. This means we can do the above in just one line:

```
IFS=\; read -a fields <<<"$IN"
# after this command, the IFS resets back to its previous value (here, the default):
set | grep ^IFS=
# IFS=$' \t\n'
```

We can see that the string `IN` has been stored into an array named `fields`, split on the semicolons:

```
set | grep ^fields=\\\|^IN=
# fields=([0]="bla@some.com" [1]="john@home.com" [2]="Full Name <fulnam@other.org>")
# IN='bla@some.com;john@home.com;Full Name <fulnam@other.org>'
```

(We can also display the contents of these variables using `declare -p`:)

```
declare -p IN fields
# declare -- IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com;Full Name <fulnam@other.org>"
# declare -a fields=([0]="bla@some.com" [1]="john@home.com" [2]="Full Name <fulnam@other.org>")
```

Note that `read` is the *quickest* way to do the split because there are no *forks* or external resources called.

Once the array is defined, you can use a simple loop to process each field (or, rather, each element in the array you've now defined):

```
# `"${fields[@]}"` expands to return every element of `fields` array as a separate argument
for x in "${fields[@]}" ;do
    echo "> [$x]"
    done
# > [bla@some.com]
# > [john@home.com]
# > [Full Name <fulnam@other.org>]
```

Or you could drop each field from the array after processing using a *shifting* approach, which I like:

```
while [ "$fields" ] ;do
    echo "> [$fields]"
    # slice the array 
    fields=("${fields[@]:1}")
    done
# > [bla@some.com]
# > [john@home.com]
# > [Full Name <fulnam@other.org>]
```

And if you just want a simple printout of the array, you don't even need to loop over it:

```
printf "> [%s]\n" "${fields[@]}"
# > [bla@some.com]
# > [john@home.com]
# > [Full Name <fulnam@other.org>]
```

#### Update: recent [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) >= 4.4

In newer versions of `bash`, you can also play with the command `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -td \; fields < <(printf "%s\0" "$IN")
```

This syntax preserve special chars, newlines and empty fields!

If you don't want to include empty fields, you could do the following:

```
mapfile -td \; fields <<<"$IN"
fields=("${fields[@]%$'\n'}")   # drop '\n' added by '<<<'
```

With `mapfile`, you can also skip declaring an array and implicitly "loop" over the delimited elements, calling a function on each:

```
myPubliMail() {
    printf "Seq: %6d: Sending mail to '%s'..." $1 "$2"
    # mail -s "This is not a spam..." "$2" </path/to/body
    printf "\e[3D, done.\n"
}

mapfile < <(printf "%s\0" "$IN") -td \; -c 1 -C myPubliMail
```

(Note: the `\0` at end of the format string is useless if you don't care about empty fields at end of the string or they're not present.)

```
mapfile < <(echo -n "$IN") -td \; -c 1 -C myPubliMail

# Seq:      0: Sending mail to 'bla@some.com', done.
# Seq:      1: Sending mail to 'john@home.com', done.
# Seq:      2: Sending mail to 'Full Name <fulnam@other.org>', done.
```

*Or* you could use `<<<`, and in the function body include some processing to drop the newline it adds:

```
myPubliMail() {
    local seq=$1 dest="${2%$'\n'}"
    printf "Seq: %6d: Sending mail to '%s'..." $seq "$dest"
    # mail -s "This is not a spam..." "$dest" </path/to/body
    printf "\e[3D, done.\n"
}

mapfile <<<"$IN" -td \; -c 1 -C myPubliMail

# Renders the same output:
# Seq:      0: Sending mail to 'bla@some.com', done.
# Seq:      1: Sending mail to 'john@home.com', done.
# Seq:      2: Sending mail to 'Full Name <fulnam@other.org>', done.
```

### Split string based on delimiter in [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)

If you can't use `bash`, or if you want to write something that can be used in many different shells, you often **can't** use *[bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)* -- and this includes the arrays we've been using in the solutions above.

However, we don't need to use arrays to loop over "elements" of a string. There is a syntax used in many shells for deleting substrings of a string from the *first* or *last* occurrence of a pattern. Note that `*` is a wildcard that stands for zero or more characters:

(The lack of this approach in any solution posted so far is the main reason I'm writing this answer ;)

```
${var#*SubStr}  # drops substring from start of string up to first occurrence of `SubStr`
${var##*SubStr} # drops substring from start of string up to last occurrence of `SubStr`
${var%SubStr*}  # drops substring from last occurrence of `SubStr` to end of string
${var%%SubStr*} # drops substring from first occurrence of `SubStr` to end of string
```

As explained by [Score_Under](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/47972612?noredirect=1):

> `#` and `%` delete the shortest possible matching substring from the *start* and *end* of the string respectively, and
>
> `##` and `%%` delete the longest possible matching substring.

Using the above syntax, we can create an approach where we extract substring "elements" from the string by deleting the substrings up to or after the delimiter.

The codeblock below works well in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (including Mac OS's `bash`), [dash](/questions/tagged/dash), [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh), [lksh](/questions/tagged/lksh), [yash](/questions/tagged/yash), [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), and [busybox](/questions/tagged/busybox)'s [ash](/questions/tagged/ash):

(Thanks to [Adam Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519360/adam-katz)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/120591261?noredirect=1), making this loop a lot simplier!)

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com;Full Name <fulnam@other.org>"
while [ "$IN" != "$iter" ] ;do
    # extract the substring from start of string up to delimiter.
    iter=${IN%%;*}
    # delete this first "element" AND next separator, from $IN.
    IN="${IN#$iter;}"
    # Print (or doing anything with) the first "element".
    printf '> [%s]\n' "$iter"
done
# > [bla@some.com]
# > [john@home.com]
# > [Full Name <fulnam@other.org>]
```

### Why not `cut`?

`cut` is useful for extracting columns in big files, but doing *forks* repetitively (`var=$(echo ... | cut ...)`) become quickly overkill!

Here is a correct syntax, tested under many [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) using `cut`, as suggested by [This other answer from DougW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903172/1765658):

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com;Full Name <fulnam@other.org>"
i=1
while iter=$(echo "$IN"|cut -d\; -f$i) ; [ -n "$iter" ] ;do
    printf '> [%s]\n' "$iter"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

I wrote this in order to compare **execution time**.

On my raspberrypi, this look like:

```
$ export TIMEFORMAT=$'(%U + %S) / \e[1m%R\e[0m : %P  '
$ time sh splitDemo.sh >/dev/null
(0.000 + 0.019) / 0.019 : 99.63  
$ time sh splitDemo_cut.sh >/dev/null
(0.051 + 0.041) / 0.188 : 48.98
```

Where overall execution time is something like 10x longer, using **1** *forks* to `cut`, **by field**!

Comment: The `#`, `##`, `%`, and `%%` substitutions have what is IMO an easier explanation to remember (for how much they delete): `#` and `%` delete the shortest possible matching string, and `##` and `%%` delete the longest possible.

Comment: The `IFS=\; read -a fields <<<"$var"` fails on newlines and add a trailing newline. The other solution removes a trailing empty field.

Comment: Could the last alternative be used with a list of field separators set somewhere else?
For instance, I mean to use this as a shell script, and pass a list of field separators as a positional parameter.

Comment: Yes, in a loop: `for sep in "#" "ł" "@" ; do ... var="${var#*$sep}" ...`

Comment: `IFS=/ read -a rr <<< "litecoin/8332/19332"; echo ${rr[@]}` produces `litecoi  8332 19332` on bash v5.0.17 -- you'll notice it mangles my first element

Comment: @ekkis Can't reproduce (even using *`bash 5.0.17(1)-release`*!). What's output of `declare -p rr`

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I can't reproduce it myself now. odd

Comment: Who cares about ms slower execution times? Readability (for easy maintenance) is surely more important in the vast majority of use cases in modern times. I've gone with `cut` for that reason. But I was looking for something POSIX sh compatible and your post gives great background to that so +1

Comment: @moo  1. This is not *"microsecond"*, it is ***"10x slower"*** 2. By repetition, this kind of small difference quickly becomes monstrous!! When [a script takes up to several hours to do a job, when *near same script* can do the same job in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67498861/1765658), this kind of concern becomes significant!!

Comment: Agreed but only if it's in your inner loop. Otherwise, the more readable version is always better. This code runs once in my script.

Comment: @moo There is a lot of script using `timeStampVar=$(date -d "$dateString" +%s)` repetitively,  when [`date -S` could be run in background...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49195703/1765658); And yes this seem not more *readable*, but once into a function, using `dateToEpoch -v varname "$dateString"` could be acceptable! Mostly if your script become improved from 1 or two seconds to near instant.

Answer (score 176):

This worked for me:

```
string="1;2"
echo $string | cut -d';' -f1 # output is 1
echo $string | cut -d';' -f2 # output is 2
```

Comment: Though it only works with a single character delimiter, that's what the OP was looking for (records delimited by a semicolon).

Comment: Answered about four years ago by [@Ashok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12328162/4215651), and also, more than one year ago by [@DougW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903172/4215651), than your answer, with even more information. Please post different solution than others'.

Comment: This is the most concise and grokable `cut` example imo.

Comment: As http://shellcheck.net/ will readily reveal, this will break on some input strings because of the lack of quoting. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) (secret TLDR: basically always, at least until you understand when you can or even should omit quotes).

Answer (score 158):

I think [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is the best and efficient command to resolve your problem. AWK is included by default in almost every Linux distribution.

```
echo "bla@some.com;john@home.com" | awk -F';' '{print $1,$2}'
```

will give

```
bla@some.com john@home.com
```

Of course your can store each email address by redefining the awk print field.

Comment: Or even simpler:

echo "bla@some.com;john@home.com" | awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"} {print}'

Comment: @Jaro This worked perfectly for me when I had a string with commas and needed to reformat it into lines.  Thanks.

Comment: It worked in this scenario -> "echo "$SPLIT_0" | awk -F' inode=' '{print $1}'"! I had problems when trying to use atrings (" inode=") instead of characters (";"). $ 1, $ 2, $ 3, $ 4 are set as positions in an array! If there is a way of setting an array... better! Thanks!

Comment: @EduardoLucio, what I'm thinking about is maybe you can first replace your delimiter `inode=` into `;` for example by `sed -i 's/inode\=/\;/g' your_file_to_process`, then define `-F';'` when apply `awk`, hope that can help you.

Answer (score 102):

How about this approach:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com" 
set -- "$IN" 
IFS=";"; declare -a Array=($*) 
echo "${Array[@]}" 
echo "${Array[0]}" 
echo "${Array[1]}"
```

[Source](http://antonolsen.com/2006/04/10/bash-split-a-string-without-cut-or-awk/)

Comment: +1 ... but I wouldn't name the variable "Array" ... pet peev I guess.  Good solution.

Comment: +1 ... but the "set" and declare -a are unnecessary. You could as well  have used just `IFS";" && Array=($IN)`

Comment: +1 Only a side note: shouldn't it be recommendable to keep the old IFS and then restore it? (as shown by stefanB in his edit3) people landing here (sometimes just copying and pasting a solution) might not think about this

Comment: -1: First, @ata is right that most of the commands in this do nothing. Second, it uses word-splitting to form the array, and doesn't do anything to inhibit glob-expansion when doing so (so if you have glob characters in any of the array elements, those elements are replaced with matching filenames).

Comment: Suggest to use `$'...'`: `IN=$'bla@some.com;john@home.com;bet <d@\ns* kl.com>'`. Then `echo "${Array[2]}"` will print a string with newline. `set -- "$IN"` is also neccessary in this case. Yes, to prevent glob expansion, the solution should include `set -f`.

Comment: The external link does not explain this code. Please add an explanation for `set` and for `$*`.

Comment: link is outdated

Answer (score 93):

```
echo "bla@some.com;john@home.com" | sed -e 's/;/\n/g'
bla@some.com
john@home.com
```

Comment: -1 **what if the string contains spaces?** for example `IN="this is first line; this is second line" arrIN=( $( echo "$IN" | sed -e 's/;/\n/g' ) )` will produce an array of 8 elements in this case (an element for each word space separated), rather than 2 (an element for each line semi colon separated)

Comment: @Luca No the sed script creates exactly two lines. What creates the multiple entries for you is when you put it into a bash array (which splits on white space by default)

Comment: That's exactly the point: the OP needs to store entries into an array to loop over it, as you can see in his edits. I think your (good) answer missed to mention to use `arrIN=( $( echo "$IN" | sed -e 's/;/\n/g' ) )` to achieve that, and to advice to change IFS to `IFS=$'\n'` for those who land here in the future and needs to split a string containing spaces. (and to restore it back afterwards). :)

Comment: @Luca Good point. However the array assignment was not in the initial question when I wrote up that answer.

Answer (score 73):

This also works:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
echo ADD1=`echo $IN | cut -d \; -f 1`
echo ADD2=`echo $IN | cut -d \; -f 2`
```

Be careful, this solution is not always correct. In case you pass "bla@some.com" only, it will assign it to both ADD1 and ADD2.

Comment: You can use -s to avoid the mentioned problem:
http://superuser.com/questions/896800/cut-lies-if-delimeter-doesn-t-exist

"-f, --fields=LIST
select only these fields; also print any line that contains no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified"

Answer (score 44):

A different take on [Darron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash/3704011#3704011), this is how I do it:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
read ADDR1 ADDR2 <<<$(IFS=";"; echo $IN)
```

Comment: I think it does! Run the commands above and then "echo $ADDR1 ... $ADDR2" and i get "bla@some.com ... john@home.com" output

Comment: This worked REALLY well for me... I used it to itterate over an array of strings which contained comma separated DB,SERVER,PORT data to use mysqldump.

Comment: Diagnosis: the `IFS=";"` assignment exists only in the `$(...; echo $IN)` subshell; this is why some readers (including me) initially think it won't work. I assumed that all of $IN was getting slurped up by ADDR1. But nickjb is correct; it does work. The reason is that `echo $IN` command parses its arguments using the current value of $IFS, but then echoes them to stdout using a space delimiter, regardless of the setting of $IFS. So the net effect is as though one had called `read ADDR1 ADDR2 <<< "bla@some.com john@home.com"` (note the input is space-separated not ;-separated).

Comment: This fails on spaces and newlines, and also expand wildcards `*` in the `echo $IN` with an unquoted variable expansion.

Comment: I really like this solution.  A description of why it works would be very useful and make it a better overall answer.

Comment: why does this work with variable ($IN) but does not work with static quoted text?
`read ADDR1 ADDR2 <<<$(IFS=";"; echo "bla@some.com;john@home.com")`

Answer (score 41):

How about this one liner, if you're not using arrays:

```
IFS=';' read ADDR1 ADDR2 <<<$IN
```

Comment: Consider using `read -r ...` to ensure that, for example, the two characters "\t" in the input end up as the same two characters in your variables (instead of a single tab char).

Comment: -1 This is not working here (ubuntu 12.04). Adding `echo "ADDR1 $ADDR1"\n echo "ADDR2 $ADDR2"` to your snippet will output `ADDR1 bla@some.com john@home.com\nADDR2` (\n is newline)

Comment: This is probably due to a bug involving `IFS` and here strings that was fixed in `bash` 4.3. Quoting `$IN` should fix it. (In theory, `$IN` is not subject to word splitting or globbing after it expands, meaning the quotes should be unnecessary. Even in 4.3, though, there's at least one bug remaining--reported and scheduled to be fixed--so quoting remains a good idea.)

Comment: This breaks if $in contain newlines even if $IN is quoted. And adds a trailing newline.

Comment: A problem with this, and many other solutions is also that it assumes there are EXACTLY TWO elements in $IN - OR that you're willing to have the second and subsequent items smashed together in ADDR2.  I understand that this meets the ask, but it's a time bomb.

Answer (score 40):

In Bash, a bullet proof way, that will work even if your variable contains newlines:

```
IFS=';' read -d '' -ra array < <(printf '%s;\0' "$in")
```

Look:

```
$ in=$'one;two three;*;there is\na newline\nin this field'
$ IFS=';' read -d '' -ra array < <(printf '%s;\0' "$in")
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="one" [1]="two three" [2]="*" [3]="there is
a newline
in this field")'
```

The trick for this to work is to use the `-d` option of `read` (delimiter) with an empty delimiter, so that `read` is forced to read everything it's fed. And we feed `read` with exactly the content of the variable `in`, with no trailing newline thanks to `printf`. Note that's we're also putting the delimiter in `printf` to ensure that the string passed to `read` has a trailing delimiter. Without it, `read` would trim potential trailing empty fields:

```
$ in='one;two;three;'    # there's an empty field
$ IFS=';' read -d '' -ra array < <(printf '%s;\0' "$in")
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three" [3]="")'
```

the trailing empty field is preserved.

---

## Update for Bash≥4.4

Since Bash 4.4, the builtin `mapfile` (aka `readarray`) supports the `-d` option to specify a delimiter. Hence another canonical way is:

```
mapfile -d ';' -t array < <(printf '%s;' "$in")
```

Comment: I found it as the rare solution on that list that works correctly with `\n`, spaces and `*` simultaneously. Also, no loops; array variable is accessible in the shell after execution (contrary to the highest upvoted answer). Note, `in=$'...'`, it does not work with double quotes. I think, it needs more upvotes.

Comment: The `mapfile` example fails if I want to use `%` as the delimiter. I suggest `printf '%s' "$in%"`.

Comment: @RobinA.Meade use `printf '%s%%'` instead: use `%%` to have a single percent sign in `printf`'s format specifier.

Answer (score 34):

Without setting the IFS

If you just have one colon you can do that:

```
a="foo:bar"
b=${a%:*}
c=${a##*:}
```

you will get:

```
b = foo
c = bar
```

Answer (score 24):

Here is a clean 3-liner:

```
in="foo@bar;bizz@buzz;fizz@buzz;buzz@woof"
IFS=';' list=($in)
for item in "${list[@]}"; do echo $item; done
```

where `IFS` delimit words based on the separator and `()` is used to create an [array](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays). Then `[@]` is used to return each item as a separate word.

If you've any code after that, you also need to restore `$IFS`, e.g. `unset IFS`.

Comment: The use of `$in` unquoted allows wildcards to be expanded.

Answer (score 15):

The following Bash/zsh function splits its first argument on the delimiter given by the second argument:

```
split() {
    local string="$1"
    local delimiter="$2"
    if [ -n "$string" ]; then
        local part
        while read -d "$delimiter" part; do
            echo $part
        done <<< "$string"
        echo $part
    fi
}
```

For instance, the command

```
$ split 'a;b;c' ';'
```

yields

```
a
b
c
```

This output may, for instance, be piped to other commands. Example:

```
$ split 'a;b;c' ';' | cat -n
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

Compared to the other solutions given, this one has the following advantages:

- `IFS` is not overriden: Due to dynamic scoping of even local variables, overriding `IFS` over a loop causes the new value to leak into function calls performed from within the loop.
- Arrays are not used: Reading a string into an array using `read` requires the flag `-a` in Bash and `-A` in zsh.

If desired, the function may be put into a script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

split() {
    # ...
}

split "$@"
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with delimiters longer than 1 character: split=$(split "$content" "file://")

Comment: True - from `help read`: `-d delim continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather than newline`

Answer (score 13):

So many answers and so many complexities. Try out a simpler solution:

```
echo "string1, string2" | tr , "\n"
```

`tr` (read, translate) replaces the first argument with the second argument in the input.

So `tr` , "\n" replace the comma with new line character in the input and it becomes:

```
string1
string2
```

Comment: This prints both tokens but does not place them in variables. (And therefore doesn't fully answer the question. You might be able to tweak your answer to make it work.)

Comment: This is a exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/918898/735926.

Answer (score 12):

There is a simple and smart way like this:

```
echo "add:sfff" | xargs -d: -i  echo {}
```

But you must use gnu xargs, BSD xargs cant support -d delim.  If you use apple mac like me.  You can install gnu xargs :

```
brew install findutils
```

then

```
echo "add:sfff" | gxargs -d: -i  echo {}
```

Answer (score 12):

you can apply awk to many situations

```
echo "bla@some.com;john@home.com"|awk -F';' '{printf "%s\n%s\n", $1, $2}'
```

also you can use this

```
echo "bla@some.com;john@home.com"|awk -F';' '{print $1,$2}' OFS="\n"
```

Answer (score 10):

There are some cool answers here (errator esp.), but for something analogous to split in other languages -- which is what I took the original question to mean -- I settled on this:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
declare -a a="(${IN//;/ })";
```

Now `${a[0]}`, `${a[1]}`, etc, are as you would expect. Use `${#a[*]}` for number of terms. Or to iterate, of course:

```
for i in ${a[*]}; do echo $i; done
```

IMPORTANT NOTE:

This works in cases where there are no spaces to worry about, which solved my problem, but may not solve yours. Go with the `$IFS` solution(s) in that case.

Comment: Does not work when `IN` contains more than two e-mail addresses. Please refer to same idea (but fixed) at [palindrom's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5257398/938111)

Comment: Better use `${IN//;/ }` (double slash) to make it also work with more than two values. Beware that any wildcard (`*?[`) will be expanded. And a trailing empty field will be discarded.

Answer (score 5):

If no space, Why not this?

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
arr=(`echo $IN | tr ';' ' '`)

echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[1]}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest way to do it.

```
spo='one;two;three'
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=';'
spo_array=($spo)
IFS=$OIFS
echo ${spo_array[*]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"

IFS=';' read ADDR1 ADDR2 <<< "${IN}"
```

Sample output:

```
echo "${ADDR1}"  # prints "bla@some.com"
echo "${ADDR2}"  # prints "john@home.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fantastic answers that were already provided, if it is just a matter of printing out the data you may consider using `awk`:

```
awk -F";" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("> [%s]\n", $i)}' <<< "$IN"
```

This sets the field separator to `;`, so that it can loop through the fields with a `for` loop and print accordingly.

#### Test

```
$ IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
$ awk -F";" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("> [%s]\n", $i)}' <<< "$IN"
> [bla@some.com]
> [john@home.com]
```

With another input:

```
$ awk -F";" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("> [%s]\n", $i)}' <<< "a;b;c   d;e_;f"
> [a]
> [b]
> [c   d]
> [e_]
> [f]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
IFS=';'
read -a IN_arr <<< "${IN}"
for entry in "${IN_arr[@]}"
do
    echo $entry
done
```

Output

```
bla@some.com
john@home.com
```

System : Ubuntu 12.04.1

Comment: IFS is not getting set in the specific context of `read` here and hence it can upset rest of the code, if any.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `set` built-in to load up the `$@` array:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
IFS=';'; set $IN; IFS=$' \t\n'
```

Then, let the party begin:

```
echo $#
for a; do echo $a; done
ADDR1=$1 ADDR2=$2
```

Comment: Better use `set -- $IN` to avoid some issues with "$IN" starting with dash. Still, the unquoted expansion of `$IN` will expand wildcards (`*?[`).

Answer (score 2):

Two bourne-ish alternatives where neither require bash arrays:

**Case 1**: Keep it nice and simple: Use a NewLine as the Record-Separator... eg.

```
IN="bla@some.com
john@home.com"

while read i; do
  # process "$i" ... eg.
    echo "[email:$i]"
done <<< "$IN"
```

Note: in this first case no sub-process is forked to assist with list manipulation.

Idea: Maybe it is worth using NL extensively *internally*, and only converting to a different RS when generating the final result *externally*.

**Case 2**: Using a ";" as a record separator... eg.

```
NL="
" IRS=";" ORS=";"

conv_IRS() {
  exec tr "$1" "$NL"
}

conv_ORS() {
  exec tr "$NL" "$1"
}

IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
IN="$(conv_IRS ";" <<< "$IN")"

while read i; do
  # process "$i" ... eg.
    echo -n "[email:$i]$ORS"
done <<< "$IN"
```

In both cases a sub-list can be composed within the loop is persistent after the loop has completed.  This is useful when manipulating lists in memory, instead storing lists in files. {p.s. keep calm and carry on B-) }

Answer (score 2):

```
IN='bla@some.com;john@home.com;Charlie Brown <cbrown@acme.com;!"#$%&/()[]{}*? are no problem;simple is beautiful :-)'
set -f
oldifs="$IFS"
IFS=';'; arrayIN=($IN)
IFS="$oldifs"
for i in "${arrayIN[@]}"; do
echo "$i"
done
set +f
```

Output:

```
bla@some.com
john@home.com
Charlie Brown <cbrown@acme.com
!"#$%&/()[]{}*? are no problem
simple is beautiful :-)
```

Explanation: Simple assignment using parenthesis () converts semicolon separated list into an array provided you have correct IFS while doing that. Standard FOR loop handles individual items in that array as usual.
Notice that the list given for IN variable must be "hard" quoted, that is, with single ticks.

IFS must be saved and restored since Bash does not treat an assignment the same way as a command. An alternate workaround is to wrap the assignment inside a function and call that function with a modified IFS. In that case separate saving/restoring of IFS is not needed. Thanks for "Bize" for pointing that out.

Comment: `!"#$%&/()[]{}*? are no problem` well... not quite: `[]*?` are glob characters. So what about creating this directory and file: `mkdir '!"#$%&'; touch '!"#$%&/()[]{} got you hahahaha - are no problem' and running your command? simple may be beautiful, but when it's broken, it's broken.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf  The string is stored in a variable. Please see the original question.

Comment: @ajaaskel you didn't fully understand my comment. Go in a scratch directory and issue these commands: `mkdir '!"#$%&'; touch '!"#$%&/()[]{} got you hahahaha - are no problem'`. They will only create a directory and a file, with weird looking names, I must admit. Then run your commands with the exact `IN` you gave: `IN='bla@some.com;john@home.com;Charlie Brown <cbrown@acme.com;!"#$%&/()[]{}*? are no problem;simple is beautiful :-)'`. You'll see that you won't get the output you expect. Because you're using a method subject to pathname expansions to split your string.

Comment: This is to demonstrate that the characters `*`, `?`, `[...]` and even, if `extglob` is set, `!(...)`, `@(...)`, `?(...)`, `+(...)` _are_ problems with this method!

Comment: One more argument against your method for the road: if someone uses this method with `nullglob` or `failglob` set, there'll be some surprises! you can try it: run your code with `shopt -s nullglob` and also with `shopt -s failglob`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf   Thanks for detailed comments on globbing.  I adjusted the code to have globbing off.  My point was however just to show that rather simple assignment can do the splitting job.

Answer (score 2):

In Android shell, most of the proposed methods just do not work:

```
$ IFS=':' read -ra ADDR <<<"$PATH"                             
/system/bin/sh: can't create temporary file /sqlite_stmt_journals/mksh.EbNoR10629: No such file or directory
```

What does work is:

```
$ for i in ${PATH//:/ }; do echo $i; done
/sbin
/vendor/bin
/system/sbin
/system/bin
/system/xbin
```

where `//` means global replacement.

Comment: Fails if any part of $PATH contains spaces (or newlines). Also expands wildcards (asterisk *, question mark ? and braces […]).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer!

```
DELIMITER_VAL='='

read -d '' F_ABOUT_DISTRO_R <<"EOF"
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.4 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
EOF

SPLIT_NOW=$(awk -F$DELIMITER_VAL '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s\n", $i}}' <<<"${F_ABOUT_DISTRO_R}")
while read -r line; do
   SPLIT+=("$line")
done <<< "$SPLIT_NOW"
for i in "${SPLIT[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Why this approach is "the best" for me?

Because of two reasons:

1. You do **not need to escape** the delimiter;
2. You will not have **problem with blank spaces**. The value will be properly separated in the array.

Comment: FYI, `/etc/os-release` and `/etc/lsb-release` are meant to be sourced, and not parsed. So your method is really wrong. Moreover, you're not quite answering the question about _spiltting a string on a delimiter._

Comment: The Awk shenanigan is just a clumsy way to reimplement `IFS="=" read -r`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf The "release" files are irrelevant to the question. I believe you didn't look at the `DELIMITER_VAL='='` variable, right? Anyway, thanks for the contribution. 

Comment: @tripleee Regarding your comment about "awk" I would do some tests to evaluate all scenarios. Anyway "awk" is universally present in all major Linux distributions. So I don't see any problems using it. 

Comment: I have nothing against Awk but using it to clumsily attempt to replace shell built-ins is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner to split a string separated by ';' into an array is:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
ADDRS=( $(IFS=";" echo "$IN") )
echo ${ADDRS[0]}
echo ${ADDRS[1]}
```

This only sets IFS in a subshell, so you don't have to worry about saving and restoring its value.

Comment: -1  
this doesn't work here (ubuntu 12.04). it prints only the first echo with all $IN value in it, while the second is empty. you can see it if you put echo "0: "${ADDRS[0]}\n echo "1: "${ADDRS[1]} the output is`0: bla@some.com;john@home.com\n 1:` (\n is new line)

Comment: please refer to nickjb's answer at for a working alternative to this idea stackoverflow.com/a/6583589/1032370

Comment: -1, 1. IFS isn't being set in that subshell (it's being passed to the environment of "echo", which is a builtin, so nothing is happening anyway). 2. `$IN` is quoted so it isn't subject to IFS splitting. 3. The process substitution is split by whitespace, but this may corrupt the original data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but works with `*` and spaces:

```
IN="bla@so me.com;*;john@home.com"
for i in `delims=${IN//[^;]}; seq 1 $((${#delims} + 1))`
do
   echo "> [`echo $IN | cut -d';' -f$i`]"
done
```

Outputs

```
> [bla@so me.com]
> [*]
> [john@home.com]
```

Other example (delimiters at beginning and end):

```
IN=";bla@so me.com;*;john@home.com;"
> []
> [bla@so me.com]
> [*]
> [john@home.com]
> []
```

Basically it removes every character other than `;` making `delims` eg. `;;;`. Then it does `for` loop from `1` to `number-of-delimiters` as counted by `${#delims}`. The final step is to safely get the `$i`th part using `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
ADDR1=${IN%%;*}
ADDR2=${IN##*;}
```

Comment: This only works for two variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first 200...

```
bash-4.2# for i in {1..200}; do echo $XXX | cut -d":" -f $i; done
```

Instead of "`echo $XXX`" you can also write a command like "`echo $PATH`" or something.

*since this is the 31st answer there should be some justification: it is unique in that it uses range and cut

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple POSIX-compatible answer nobody has mentioned:

```
sIFS=$IFS
IFS=';'
for e in $IN; do
    echo "[$e]"
done
IFS=$sIFS
```

If you want save it to an array to process later, here's [a trick](https://lore.kernel.org/git/4A028A0A.5070003@viscovery.net/) I learned from the git mailing list:

```
# store in $@
sIFS=$IFS
IFS=';'
set -- $IN
IFS=$sIFS

# traverse $@
for e; do
    echo "[$e]"
done
```

If all you want is to do some formatting, then:

```
sIFS=$IFS
IFS=';'
printf '[%s]\n' $IN
IFS=$sIFS
```

Simple, efficient, and **portable**.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**
I'm sorry, I had read somewhere on SO that `perl` is required by POSIX, so I thought it would be legitimate to use it.
But on unix.stackexchange.com, several users state `perl` is NOT part of the POSIX specification.

My solution: A function that uses `perl`'s `split` to do the work.

With detailed comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This function is a wrapper for Perl's split.\
# \
# Since we cannot return an array like in Perl,
# it takes the name of the resulting array as last
# argument.\
# \
# See https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split for usage info
# and examples.\
# \
# If you provide a Perl regexp that contains e. g. an escaped token like \b,
# space(s) and/or capture group(s), it must be quoted, and e. g. /\b/ must
# be single-quoted.\
# Thus, it's best to generally single-quote a Perl regexp.
function split # Args: <Element separator regexp> <string> <array name>
{
    (($# != 3)) && echo "${FUNCNAME[0]}: Wrong number of arguments, returning." && return 1

    local elementSepRE=$1
    local string=$2
    local -n array=$3

    local element i=0

    # Attention! read does Word Splitting on each line!
    # I must admit I didn't know that so far.
    # This removes leading and trailing spaces, exactly
    # what we don't want.
    # Thus, we set IFS locally to newline only.
    local IFS=$'\n'

    while read element; do
        # As opposed to array+=($element),
        # this preserves leading and trailing spaces.
        array[i++]=$element
    done <<<$(_perl_split)
}

# This function calls Perl's split function and prints the elements of the
# resulting array on separate lines.\
# It uses the caller's $elementSepRE and $string.
function _perl_split
{
    # A heredoc is a great way of embedding a Perl script.
    # N.B.: - Shell variables get expanded.
    #         - Thus:
    #           - They must be quoted.
    #           - Perl scalar variables must be escaped.
    #       - The backslash of \n must be escaped to protect it.
    #       - Instead of redirecting a single heredoc to perl, we may
    #         use multiple heredocs with cat within a command group and
    #         pipe the result to perl.
    #         This enables us to conditionally add certain lines of code.

    {
        cat <<-END
            my \$elementSepRE=q($elementSepRE);
        END

        # If $elementSepRE is a literal Perl regexp, qr must be applied
        # to it in order to use it.
        # N.B.: We cannot write this condition in Perl because when perl
        # compiles the script, all statements are checked for validity,
        # no matter if they will actually be executed or not.
        # And if $elementSepRE was e. g. == ', the line below – although
        # not to be executed – would give an error because of an unterminated
        # single-quoted string.
        [[ $elementSepRE =~ ^m?/ && $elementSepRE =~ /[msixpodualn]*$ ]] && cat <<-END
            \$elementSepRE=qr$elementSepRE;
        END

        cat <<-END
            my @array=split(\$elementSepRE, q($string));

            print(\$_ . "\\n") for (@array);
        END
    } | perl
}
```

And the same without comments for those who see at a glance what's going on ;)

```
#!/bin/bash

# This function is a wrapper for Perl's split.\
# \
# Since we cannot return an array like in Perl,
# it takes the name of the resulting array as last
# argument.\
# \
# See https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split for usage info
# and examples.\
# \
# If you provide a Perl regexp that contains e. g. an escaped token like \b,
# space(s) and/or capture group(s), it must be quoted, and e. g. /\b/ must
# be single-quoted.\
# Thus, it's best to generally single-quote a Perl regexp.
function split # Args: <Element separator regexp> <string> <array name>
{
    (($# != 3)) && echo "${FUNCNAME[0]}: Wrong number of arguments, returning." && return 1

    local elementSepRE=$1
    local string=$2
    local -n array=$3

    local element i=0

    local IFS=$'\n'

    while read element; do
        array[i++]=$element
    done <<<$(_perl_split)
}

function _perl_split
{
    {
        cat <<-END
            my \$elementSepRE=q($elementSepRE);
        END

        [[ $elementSepRE =~ ^m?/ && $elementSepRE =~ /[msixpodualn]*$ ]] && cat <<-END
            \$elementSepRE=qr$elementSepRE;
        END

        cat <<-END
            my @array=split(\$elementSepRE, q($string));

            print(\$_ . "\\n") for (@array);
        END
    } | perl
}
```

Answer (score -8):

There are two simple methods:

```
cat "text1;text2;text3" | tr " " "\n"
```

and

```
cat "text1;text2;text3" | sed -e 's/ /\n/g'
```

Comment: I think you have `cat` and `echo` confused. `cat` reads from files. `echo` reads text given.

Answer (score -11):

Yet another late answer... If you are java minded, here is the **bashj** (https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashj/) solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/bashj

#!java

private static String[] cuts;
private static int cnt=0;
public static void split(String words,String regexp) {cuts=words.split(regexp);}
public static String next() {return(cnt<cuts.length ? cuts[cnt++] : "null");}

#!bash

IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"

: j.split($IN,";")    # java method call

while true
do
    NAME=j.next()     # java method call
    if [ $NAME != null ] ; then echo $NAME ; else exit ; fi
done
```

Comment: You cannot expect someone to change their shell just so that—they'll be able to perform a single task.