# How to get part of the string in BASH

Tags: bash

My code

```
FOO="aaa;bbb;ccc"

echo ${FOO##*;} # Result: ccc
echo ${FOO%%;*} # Result: aaa
```

how to get "bbb" from var FOO?

```
echo ${FOO???*} # Result: bbb
```

thank you

Comment: Do you have to do it via bash parameter expansion, or is using awk acceptable?

Comment: Please no awk, bash pure language. Thank

Answer (score 1):

There's no explicit operator for that. Furthermore you can not nest these operators (see [Nested Shell Parameter Expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724056/nested-shell-parameter-expansion))

So you should use some temporary variable for the job:

```
FOO="aaa;bbb;ccc"
tmp=${FOO%;*}
tmp=${tmp#*;}
echo $tmp
```

Or you should convert it to an array.

Edited for the archive, thanks for the comment.

Comment: This prints `aaa`, not `bbb` as required.  Use single `%` and `#` instead of `%%` and `##`

Answer (score 1):

As per [jejese's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351649/302243) you can use the `#` and `%` word splitting constructs.

```
FOO="aaa;bbb;ccc"
split=${FOO%;*}
final=${split#*;}
echo $final
```

produces:

```
bbb
```

Or you can use the `IFS` bash field separator variable set to a semicolon to split your input based on fields.  This probably simpler to use and allows you to obtain the second field's value using a single line of code.

```
FOO="aaa;bbb;ccc"
IFS=";" read field1 field2 field3 <<< "$FOO"
echo $field1 $field2 $field3
```

produces:

```
aaa bbb ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly generalize well, but extracting the middle of 3 `;`-delimited fields can be accomplished with:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ FOO=aaa;bbb;ccc
$ echo ${FOO//+(${FOO##*;}|${FOO%%;*}|;)}
bbb
```

Breaking it down into steps makes it easier to see how it works:

```
$ C=${FOO##*;}     # ccc
$ A=${FOO%%;*}     # aaa
$ echo ${FOO//+($A|$C|;)}  # Removes every occurance of $A, $C, or ; from FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way. Assign $FOO to the positional parameters:

```
IFS=';'
set -- $FOO
echo  "$2"
```