# Shell (Bash) parameter expansion expressions

Tags: bash

I have some code that converts a date in a file name into a path.

```
#!/bin/bash
aFile="bla_2016-11-24_17-24.zip" # Many files, each with same format: "bla_{year}-{month}-{day}_{hour}-{minute}.zip"
aDate=${aFile#*_} # remove "bla_"
aDate=${aDate%.*} # remove ".zip"
aDate=${aDate//_/ } # replace "_" with " "
aDate=(${aDate//-/ }) # replace "-" with " " and make array
aPath="${aDate[0]}/${aDate[1]}/${aDate[2]}/${aDate[3]}/${aDate[4]}"
mkdir -p $aPath
```

I've seen both of these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917260/can-var-parameter-expansion-expressions-be-nested-in-bash), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724056/nested-shell-parameter-expansion)), which suggest that nested parameter expansion expressions in bash scripting are not possible.

I was wondering if there might be a better way to implement my code above, more specifically reduce the length of the code. It's just five lines, so not a huge irritation if it's not possible, but it seems like I'm doing it in a dumb way.

Python solution:

```
aFile = "bla_2016-11-24_17-24.zip"

import re
aPath = "/".join(re.split("[_-]", aFile[4:-4])) # 2016/11/24/17/24
```

Comment: With GNU sed: `echo "bla_2016-11-24_17-24.zip" | sed -E 's/^[^_]+_(.*)\.zip$/\1/;s|[_-]|/|g'` Output: `2016/11/24/17/24` or with awk: `echo "bla_2016-11-24_17-24.zip" | awk -F '[_.-]' '{OFS="/"; print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'`

Comment: Nice solutions, I like them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash:

```
aFile="bla_2016-11-24_17-24.zip"
[[ ${aFile//[_.-]//} =~ ^[^/]*/(.*)/[^/]*?$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Output:

```
2016/11/24/17/24
```

Comment: I like this more than @RicardoBranco solution because it doesn't reference the array 5 times

Comment: I like it too.  Didn't know about this BASH_REMATCH feature. Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quicker Bash solution:

```
aFile="bla_2016-11-24_17-24.zip"
arr=($(echo ${aFile//[_-\.]/ }))
aPath=${arr[1]}/${arr[2]}/${arr[3]}/${arr[4]}/${arr[5]}
```

EDIT: This solution only works with recent versions of Bash such as the one shipped with Ubuntu 16.04 (4.3.46).  It fails with 4.3.30 (shipped by Debian 8).

Comment: The problem is with the version of Bash.  With version 4.1.5 (from the Docker image of Debian 6) it fails.  My version is 4.3.46 (from Ubuntu 16.04).  I fear we must debug our bashisms on older versions... :(  Which version is yours?

Comment: I was thinking the same. On MacOS though so my version was `3.2.57` or something similar. I updated, now I have `4.4.12`. I guess the latest version is too high? :o

Comment: I think it's better than having that old version.  Ubuntu 17.04 uses 4.4.5 and the upcoming Debian 9 4.4.11.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I solved this. I tried a solution with sed then realised that's dumb; I could just use my Python solution. So for anyone wondering, here's mine:

```
aFile="bla_2016-11-24_17-24.zip"
aPath="$(python -c 'import sys, re; print "/".join(re.split("[_-]", sys.argv[1][4:-4]))' "$aFile")" # 2016/11/24/17/24
```