# Bash: Nested variable expansion

Tags: bash

How can I nest operations in bash? e.g I know that

```
$(basename $var)
```

will give me just the final part of the path and

```
${name%.*}
```

gives me everything before the extension.

How do I combine these two calls, I want to do something like:

```
${$(basename $var)%.*}
```

Comment: It appears that none of the answers addresses the "real" question, i.e. is nested variable expansion possible? Without using a command line tool like `basename`.

Comment: Here an answer (though not the accepted one): https://stackoverflow.com/a/6724305/1172302

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sid-m 's answer states, you need to change the order of the two expansions because one of them (the `%` stuff) can only be applied to variables (by giving their name):

```
echo "$(basename "${var%.*}")"
```

Other things to mention:

- You should use double quotes around every expansion, otherwise you run into trouble if you have spaces in the variable values.  I already did that in my answer.
- In case you know or expect a specific file extension, `basename` can strip that off for you as well: `basename "$var" .txt`  (This will print `foo` for `foo.txt` in `$var`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```
 echo $(basename ${var%.*})
```

it is just the order that needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you explain the logic why it has to be that way around?

Comment: The `echo` is unnecessary; `basename "${var%.*}"` does the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to split the file name, here is a simple pattern :

```
$ var=/some/folder/with/file.ext
$ echo $(basename $var) | cut -d "." -f1
file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file extension in advance, you can tell `basename` to remove it, either as a second argument or via the `-s` option. Both these yield the same:

```
basename "${var}" .extension
basename -s .extension "${var}"
```

If you don't know the file extension in advance, you can try to `grep` the proper part of the string.

```
### grep any non-slash followed by anything ending in dot and non-slash
grep -oP '[^/]*(?=\.[^/]*$)' <<< "${var}"
```