# Remove prefix and extension in Shell from file

Tags: bash, shell, file-extension, prefix

I want to extract filename by removing prefix and extension.
e.g. file=foo_filename.txt

I am using this,but its not working.

```
${file#foo_%.txt}
```

Thanks

Comment: Be sure to check out [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) on Greg's Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

```
file="foo_filename.txt"
file=${file#foo_}
file=${file%.*}
echo "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it almost right:

```
file=foo_filename.txt ;  echo ${file%.txt}
```

Or for example in one step with sed:

```
file=foo_filename.txt ;  echo ${file} | sed 's/^foo_\(.*\)\..*/\1/'
```

Yet another method:

```
file=foo_filename.txt ; basename -s .txt ${file#foo_}
```

You cannot "nest" variable expansion in *bash*: [Can ${var} parameter expansion expressions be nested in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917260/can-var-expressions-be-nested-in-bash)

Comment: I want to remove foo_ as well,which is the prefix.

Comment: then you have to do it in two steps as in the other answer

Comment: It might be worth noting that the "one step" methods are about a thousand times slower than the two step method due to the required forks. They may also fail outright if the filename contains various kinds of whitespace and special characters.

Comment: that's true that they are slower