# Bash Indirect expansion doesnt seem to work in cloud build bash scripts?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Bash has indirect expansion with the following format:

```
echo ${!VARIABLE}
```

However it doesnt seem to work in a google cloud build step using the bash entrypoint. I have set the values of `_BAR` and `_FOO_BAR` under `substitutions:` and I also have `automapSubstitutions: true` so the substitutions are being set as environment variables in bash. Im trying to follow [this answer as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14204692/3255621). I have the following step:

```
- id: Test Indirect Expansion
  name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil"
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - -c
    - |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      echo "Value of substitution _BAR: ${_BAR}"
      echo "Value of substitution _FOO_BAR: ${_FOO_BAR}"
      export foobar=_FOO${_BAR}
      echo "expansion: ${foobar}"
      echo "indirect expansion: ${!foobar}"
```

However the output for the step shows indirect expansion as blank:

```
Value of substitution _BAR: _BAR
Value of substitution _FOO_BAR: google cloud
expansion: _FOO_BAR
indirect expansion:
```

These commands work on my local bash terminal but not here. I cant find anything mentioning indirect substitution for cloud build. But I dont see any reason why it wouldnt support it.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Does google cloud build use bash, or some other shell?

Comment: @GordonDavisson You can use any shell that's installed in the image. But im setting entrypoint as bash here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this seems to be a rare issue, I figured that bash scripts inside of Cloud build steps dont support this kind of indirect expansion.

I was hoping to dynamically set variable names using this. Instead I just used if statements inside the bash script to do what I needed to do, in case anyone finds this in the future.